# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::post does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Sorry for such a stupid question but im on deadend right now, Im working on a personal project using Laravel (first time btw) and i ran into some problem.

I tried to do `{{ $kategori->post()->count() }}` (this is works btw) but with Users table. I already set the foreign key and stuff.

I tried to modify the `User.php` too (See code) but still didnt work as i intended. I need some helps. And im using the Laravel "`php artisan make:auth`"

I've tried edited the Model (`User.php` and `Post.php`) and Controller but i still cant figure out whats wrong.

***Post.php***

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

***User.php***

```php
public function post()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id');
}
```

***Controller***

```php
use App\User;

// other methods in the Controller

public function index()
{
   $posts = post::paginate(5);
   $user = User::post;
   return view('index', compact('posts', 'user'));   
}
```

***blade view***

```
{{ $user->post()->count() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a `post` model that do not exist in this line:

```php
$user = User::post;
```

This should be ::**Post**.

If you just want to count the number of posts you should use the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) method, this will count the number of posts without loading them, which will give you some perfomance.

```php
$user = User::find($id)->withCount('post'); // this will count the number of posts to the given user.
return view('index', compact('user'));
```

You can access the count this way in your view:

```
{{$user->post_count}}
```

You could also count the number of posts of all users:

```php
$users = User::all()->withCount('post');
```

And do a foreach loop to access each one of them:

```php
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->post_count}}
@endforeach
```

Docs:

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

**Note:** you should name your relation `posts`, and not `post`, since its a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the main purpose of the source code
But you can use following code to count relation

```php
$user_post_count = User::find($id)->post()->count();
$all_user_with_post = User::all()->with('post');
$all_user_with_post_count = User::all()->withCount('post');
```